# getoldtweets-pythonで20件以上取得できない

Tags: python, python3

現在、getoldtweets-pythonを用いたツイート取得に取り組んでいます。
最新20件のツイートはできますが、21件以上の取得をしようとすると最新20が繰り返し取得されてしまい、目的のツイート数を取得できません何がおかしいのでしょうか。おしえていただけると助かります。

自分の環境
OS：macos mojave
python： Python 3.6.3

```
import got3 as got
username = input("username>")#指定したユーザ名を基にツイートを取得
number = int(input("number>"))#最新から何件までを取得
#ツイート取得
tweetCriteria = 
got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername(username).setMaxTweets(number)
tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
with open('tweet/'+username+'.txt','a') as f:
    for v in tweet:
        f.write(v.text+ "\n")
        print(v.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3の "got3"は実験的なもので、公式にはサポートされていません。問題が発生するようであれば、Python2の"got"の方を使った方がいいと思われます。

https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python

Comment: 助かりました。。。
2系で実行したところ目的のツイート数を取得できました
ありがとうございます。